# Unable to run HBASE from Cygwin from Windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I have configured the HBASE using the below link

https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/cygwin.html

I have configured successfully but unable to run the HBase and the errors that are displayed are not meaningful.

```
$ ./start-hbase.sh
./start-hbase.sh: line 20: $'\r': command not found
./start-hbase.sh: line 22: $'\r': command not found
./start-hbase.sh: line 28: $'\r': command not found
./start-hbase.sh: line 30: cd: $'.\r': No such file or directory
./start-hbase.sh: line 31: $'\r': command not found
./start-hbase.sh: line 35: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directory/usr/local/hbase/bin
./start-hbase.sh: line 37: $'\r': command not found
./start-hbase.sh: line 66: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am unable to understand where to start the debug.

Comment: the file is using CRLF termination instead of expected LF. Use `d2u start-hbase.sh` to change it. `d2u` is part of `dos2unix` package

Comment: Are you actually using HBase 0.94?

Comment: @matzeri Thanks for the hint I was able to solve by changing the EOL to Unix. Please post it as answer will accept it and close the threqad

Comment: @cricket_007 I am installing HBase 2.1.2 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by file using CRLF termination instead of expected LF.

Use `d2u start-hbase.sh` to change it. `d2u` is part of `dos2unix` package

Comment: Along with the above lead I have changed the EOL of the file from windows to Unix